# calling pywavelet functions wavedecand waverec from a polars dataframe

Tags: python, function, python-polars, pywavelets

I would like to call the following function ( works fine with pandas)  with a polars series..

```
import pywt
def lowpassfilter(signal, thresh = 0.63, wavelet="db4"):
    thresh = thresh*np.nanmax(signal)
    coeff = pywt.wavedec(signal, wavelet, mode="per" )
    coeff[1:] = (pywt.threshold(i, value=thresh, mode="soft" ) for i in coeff[1:])
    reconstructed_signal = pywt.waverec(coeff, wavelet, mode="per" )
    return reconstructed_signal
```

i have tried the following:

```
df = df.with_columns(pl.struct('close').map(lowpassfilter).alias('wavelet')
```

and i get a weird array "value error, buffer source aray is read only"

could someone help me, and explain how to call the fuction correctly and what i am doing wrong..

many thanks,

Answer (score 2):

So telling what exactly you are doing wrong is a little bit hard without data, but maybe this example is helping you further.
So assuming your column "close" is a list.

```
import pywt
import numpy as np
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "close": [
            [1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 115, 51, 5651, 65, 1651, 651, 651, 156],
            [1, 252, 5, 1452, 1, 1542, 115, 51, 56, 65, 51, 61, 651, 56],
        ],
        "ind": [1, 2],
    }
)


┌────────────────┬─────┐
│ close          ┆ ind │
│ ---            ┆ --- │
│ list[i64]      ┆ i64 │
╞════════════════╪═════╡
│ [1, 2, … 156]  ┆ 1   │
│ [1, 252, … 56] ┆ 2   │
└────────────────┴─────┘
```

Furthermore adapt your function to return a polars series.

```
def lowpassfilter(signal, thresh=0.63, wavelet="db4"):
    thresh = thresh * np.nanmax(signal)
    coeff = pywt.wavedec(signal, wavelet, mode="per")
    coeff[1:] = (pywt.threshold(i, value=thresh, mode="soft") for i in coeff[1:])
    reconstructed_signal = pywt.waverec(coeff, wavelet, mode="per")
    return pl.Series(reconstructed_signal)

df.with_columns(pl.col("close").map_elements(lambda x: lowpassfilter(x)))



┌───────────────────────────────────┬─────┐
│ close                             ┆ ind │
│ ---                               ┆ --- │
│ list[f64]                         ┆ i64 │
╞═══════════════════════════════════╪═════╡
│ [12.289185, -70.788354, … 296.92… ┆ 1   │
│ [-44.438136, 35.622057, … 304.48… ┆ 2   │
└───────────────────────────────────┴─────┘
```

Comment: If you're doing map_elements then the function need not return a Series. If you're doing map_batches then the function has to return a Series. Also, you don't need the `lambda x:` since you're just immediately calling the function exactly as-is. You can just make that line `df.with_columns(pl.col("close").map_elements(lowpassfilter))`

Comment: I changed the return of the function to a series, because else you have to deal with the conversion of the column to list since if you map the function like above the resulting column will be of type Object. Or is this already somehow possible without extra conversion?
Thank you for tip with lambda, I wasn't aware of that!

Comment: just as an experiment, if I do `pl.DataFrame({'a':[2,3,4]}).with_columns(b=pl.col('a').map_elements(lambda y: [y*x for x in range(3)]))` it doesn't return an Object. I didn't install pywt so maybe different behavior there.

Comment: So the result of the function is a numpy array and then the resulting column is of type object e.g. `pl.DataFrame({'a':[2,3,4]}).with_columns(b=pl.col('a').map_elements(lambda x: np.ones(1)))`

Comment: Gotcha, guess that's the difference between an np array return and Python list.